# Cordova Plugin not working in Android (Emulator)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the cordova camera plugin (I have fetched the latest version from their github) and it is working great on iOS, but it does nothing on Android (Emulator). I'm using Ionic 1. It does open the Camera and all these things, but after I press "Save", nothing else happens.
I know I can't use the camera, so I choose pictures form camera roll. But it seems the getPicture method is never called

Here is the code:

```
    var index = btnIndex;
    var source = -1;
    if(index == 1){
      //choose from album
      if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()){
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
      }else{
        source = Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
      }
    }else if(index == 2){
      //take new picture
      source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
    }

    if(source > -1) {
      var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 320,
        targetHeight: 320,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true
      };
      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI) {
        console.log("send file to server");
        var imgTag = document.getElementById("myImage");
        alert("imageURI: " + imageURI);
        var url = SERVER.url + "upload.php";
        var opt = new FileUploadOptions();
        opt.fileName = $scope.currentUser.clientID + ".jpg";
        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, imageURI, opt)
          .then(function(result) {
            imgTag.src =  $scope.currentUser.clientID + ".jpg?" + new Date().getTime(); //time is used to refresh the image
          }, function(err) {
            alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten:  " + JSON.stringify(err));
          }, function (progress) {
            console.log("progress: " + progress);
          });
      }), function(error){
        alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      };

      $cordovaCamera.cleanup();

    }
```

Comment: Use this chrome extension to debug live and see if theres any error: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage

Comment: I've used Chrome already to debug - there are no errors. Neither are in the Android Studio Console

Comment: if `getPicture` is not called and there is no error in console, then `source` is probably still `-1`, can you confirm that `index` is being set and source is not `-1`.

Comment: Seems like `$cordovaCamera.cleanup();` caused the problems since it is not supported by Android. After removing it, it worked :)